# Fastest way of communication between multiple EC2 instances in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, performance, networking, amazon-ec2

I am looking for the absolute fastest way to submit a short string from one to multiple EC2 Instances of the type t2.nano. Example: Something happens on Instance 1, Instance 2,3,4 should (almost) instantly know about it. Target is < 5ms. For now the instances are all in the same region and same cluster availability zone.

What I have looked at so far:

- Shared drive where instance1 can drop the data and the rest of the instances can check it
  -> Not possible as this instance type does not support shared drives
- Redis
  -> I tested this locally and it is pretty slow actually, at least XXms, and sometimes XXXms for one read and one write (just for
  testing).

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you considered using some kind of messaging queue and having a fan-out architecture?

Comment: I have considered pushing data from Instance 1 to a dedicated instance via socket. socket and let the other instances check that dedicated instance for the data. however, not sure if this approach is viable, I did not test it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try AWS EFS

Multiple compute instances, including Amazon EC2, Amazon ECS, and AWS Lambda, can access an Amazon EFS file system at the same time, providing a common data source for workloads and applications running on more than one compute instance or server.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion, it is the one I chose. Performance is pretty decent.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Twisted for [Publish/Subscribe](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/#pubsubserver) between your clients, where clients see all messages posted by other clients.

Alternatively, consider [Autobahn](https://crossbar.io/autobahn/) which builds abstraction layers on Twisted including WebSocket-based pub/sub and WAMP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, I went to their chat and started to read the docs. I am sure it is possible with both of them, but they are quite complicated, and seem to have a steep learning curve. I ended up using just Amazon EFS, it is decently fast and very simple to use.

Comment: Out of interest, how are your clients detecting changes in shared state on EFS, and what kind of latency are you seeing from the time an item is changed to the time all clients notice it?